# Is there a way to determine the order of labels in scikit-learn's LabelEncoder?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Let's say I have a classification task where I want to classify text as either "Spam" or "Ham". The "precision" score (calculated "TP / (TP + FP)") would be a useful error measure to determine how many "Ham" messages were incorrectly classified as "Spam" assuming the following confusion matrix:

[image]

As far as I know, scikit-calculates the confusion matrix after the following scheme:

[image]

Now, if I use the label encoder (see code below), it would give 'Spam' the class label 1 and 'ham' the class label 0 which would reverse the confusion matrix (FP would become TN etc.) so that the precision score would get a different meaning. So, my question is if there is a way that I can tell the label encoder which label to assign to which class? (In this case it is simple, I can solve the problem with a simply list comprehension, but I am wondering if there is something already in scikit.)

So, the goal is to use LabelEncode to give 'spam' the class label 0 and 'ham' the class label 1.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

X = df['text'].values 
y = df['class'].values

print('before: %s ...' %y[:5])

le = LabelEncoder()
y = le.fit_transform(y)

print('after: %s ...' %y[:5])
```

```
before: ['spam' 'ham' 'ham' 'ham' 'ham'] ...
after: [1 0 0 0 0] ...
```

Comment: The labels are numbered in sorted order, so for words that would mean in alphabetical order.  It doesn't look like LabelEncoder provides a way of specifying a custom order.  But it would be fairly simple to write your own function that just maps your strings to numbers in whatever way you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, if you use `precision_score(... pos_label=1, ...)` you can assign the positive label to the class manually, which is important to calculate the "correct" score, since the equation for precision depends on what you "positive" class is (Precision =  tp / (tp + fp))

But a case where the labeling could cause problems was when I was doing cross-validation and, e.g., wanted to calculate the precision, since the `cross_validation` function does not have a parameter for the
"positive label"

`cross_val_score(clf, X_train, y_train, cv=cv, scoring='precision')`

However, as suggested on GitHub, a workaround is to create a "custom scorer" that you can use in cross-validation to solve the label problem:

```
from functools import partial
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score, make_scorer
custom_scorer = make_scorer(partial(precision_score, pos_label="1"))
```

Answer (score 0):

`LabelEncoder` uses the ordering built into Python, i.e. what you would get from `sorted` without a `key` or comparison function. But the evaluation metrics that are asymmetric wrt. labels take a `pos_label` keyword argument to explicitly make one class the "positive" class:

```
>>> a = np.random.randint(0, 2, 10)
>>> a
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0])
>>> precision_recall_fscore_support(a, np.ones(10), pos_label=1, average='micro')
(0.20000000000000001, 1.0, 0.33333333333333337, None)
>>> precision_recall_fscore_support(a, np.ones(10), pos_label=0, average='micro')
/home/larsmans/src/scikit-learn/sklearn/metrics/classification.py:920: UndefinedMetricWarning: Precision and F-score are ill-defined and being set to 0.0 due to no predicted samples.
(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, None)
```